# SIP RTP Stack for IVR Application

Tags: c++, sip, rtp, telecommunication

I have an IVR application which plays the prompts and records the user message and detects the DTMF. Currently the application is based on SS7 signaling and uses the PSTN based media boards for media play / record functionality.

Now I have to move this application to IP based solution. For this, I need any open-source / low-cost solution to enable SIP based signaling and RTP based media flow and G.711 encoding / decoding and support for Windows and Linux.

My application needs to handle around 500 concurrent calls, and the code is closed code so cannot be GPL'ed. I will prefer LGPL code.

I have shortlisted few solutions:

1. OSIP(LGPL) + ORTP(LGPL) + eXosip(GPL)
2. PJSIP + PJMEDIA (GPL / Licensed)
3. Radvision (Too costly).

Please suggest me what is the best option among these or else let me know if any other better option is available.

GJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radvision has a extensive sip stack and it can be used seamlessly if you are ready to pay for it.

I would suggest you can go for option 1 but you may have to tweak the code a lot to get the correct interfaces depending on the platform you are going to use it on.

Exclude GPL license based software if you dont intend to make your code open.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out VDK http://www.voipdevkit.com it is multi-platform and does not cost too much